# PostgreSQL select when parameters for search in another table string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this structure

```
parameters (
   prm_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , prm_name varchar
 , dimension_id int4
 , FOREIGN KEY (dimension_id) REFERENCES dimensions(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

points (
    pnt_id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    name text    
);  

points_parameters (
   pnt_id int
 , prm_id int
 , value text
 , PRIMARY KEY (pnt_id, prm_id, value)
 , FOREIGN KEY (prm_id) REFERENCES parameters(prm_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
 , FOREIGN KEY (pnt_id) REFERENCES points(pnt_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And I have some parameters for search: 'Depth', 'Name', 'Water', etc.

How I can build query with dynamic parameters? For example, I want to find points with parameters Depth > 4 and Water is 'true'

I think it should be

```
SELECT pnt_id
FROM points_parameters a
    LEFT JOIN parameters b ON a.prm_id = b.prm_id
WHERE b.prm_name = 'Name' AND a.value LIKE '%a'
    AND b.prm_id IN (
                        SELECT pnt_id
                         FROM points_parameters a
                             LEFT JOIN parameters b ON a.prm_id = b.prm_id
                         WHERE b.prm_name = 'Drinking water'
                             AND a.value = 'true'
                    )
```

If I need more filters, it becomes bulky.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/42ad2

Thank you!

Comment: Just joins with a couple of where filters will do! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you please create SQLFiddle for me? I'm not good in Postgre. I think it should be SELECT pnt_id FROM points_parameters a
    LEFT JOIN parameters b ON a.prm_id = b.prm_id
    WHERE b.prm_name = 'Name'
    AND a.value LIKE '%a' AND b.prm_id IN (SELECT pnt_id FROM points_parameters a
              LEFT JOIN parameters b ON a.prm_id = b.prm_id
              WHERE b.prm_name = 'Drinking water'
              AND a.value = 'true')
If I need more filters, it stand bulky(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses function [json_object_agg(name, value)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) introduced in Postgres 9.4.

You can show points parameters in json format with this query:

```
select pnt_id, pnt_name, json_object_agg(prm_name::text, value) params
from points
join points_parameters using(pnt_id)
join parameters using (prm_id)
group by 1, 2

 pnt_id | pnt_name |                         params                         
--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------
      1 | first    | { "Depth" : "10", "Water" : "true", "Crane" : "true" }
(1 row)
```

So use the json format to filter data with arbitrary set of parameters:

```
select pnt_id, pnt_name
from (
    select pnt_id, pnt_name, json_object_agg(prm_name::text, value) params
    from points
    join points_parameters using(pnt_id)
    join parameters using (prm_id)
    group by 1, 2
    ) s
where (params->>'Depth')::int > 4
and (params->>'Water')::boolean

 pnt_id | pnt_name 
--------+----------
      1 | first
(1 row)
```